# how to parse out image name from image url

Tags: c#, url

If I have any URL with an image file at the end, such as:

```
http://www.google.com/image1.jpg
http://www.google.com/test/test23/image1.jpg
```

And I want to get:

```
image1.jpg
```

What is the best way to do this in C#?

Comment: URLs use forward slashes.  Is that really what the input looks like?

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - typo

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(@"http://www.google.com/test/test23/image1.jpg");
```

Comment: Yup works with both forward and back slashes - way better answer then mine.

Answer (score 5):

As long as your sure its an image file you can just use the path class.

[System.io.path.GetFilenAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

Comment: Capitalization issue. Should be System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void doSomething() {
    string url = "http:\\www.google.com\image1.jpg";
    string imageFileName = url.Substring( url.LastIndexOf( '\\' ) + 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best, but a certainly a way

```
url = "blahblah\image1.jpg"

string imageName  = url.substring(url.lastindexof("\") + 1);
```

Comment: This is basically what Path.GetFileName is doing